# ELK Error while installing plugin to Logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, bitnami, elk

i installed ELK on a Google Cloud Platform server and wanted to install a Logstash Plugin. So i wrote this into the SSH console:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/logstash
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-mongodb
```

(a plugin to send data from mongodb to elasticsearch via logstash)

But i got the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be remove
d in a future release.
2020-03-29T09:12:29.354Z [main] WARN FilenoUtil : Native subprocess control requires open access to sun.nio.ch
Pass '--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=org.jruby.dist' or '=org.jruby.core' to enable.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/opt/bitnami/logstash/vendor/bundl
e/jruby/2.5.0/gems/jruby-openssl-0.10.4-java/lib/jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ERROR: File /opt/bitnami/logstash/Gemfile does not exist or is not writable, aborting
```

Can u help me out pls

PS: i am using ELK by Bitnami btw

Answer (score 3):

Bitnami engineer here,

This is an issue related to permissions, so please execute:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/logstash 
sudo bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-mongodb
```

Find below our get-started docs for further info:
https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/elk/get-started/get-started/

I hope it helps